# How to change CSS style for all of any specific element tag in outer div only?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let say I've below HTML code, Here I just want to change the color `<a>` element tag in outer div `#my_div_1` only.

HTML:

```
<style>
#my_div_1 a{
    color: red;
}
</style>

<div id="my_div_1">

    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>      
    <b> Not change my colour</b><br>            

    <div id="my_div_2">
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
    </div>  

    <a href="#">change the colour </a>  <br>        
    <b> Not change my colour</b> <br>               

    <div id="my_div_3"> 
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>        
    </div>

    <a href="#">change the colour </a> <br>
    <b> Not change my colour</b>  <br>       
</div>
```

But the output is:

[image]

Please correct me where I'm doing wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `>` for [the immediate children or child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). As it was before, it was selecting all descendants `<a>` (basically all `<a>` nested within `#my_div_1`)

## [Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors#Combinators)

> In CSS, combinators allow you to combine multiple selectors together, which allows you to select elements inside other elements, or adjacent to other elements. The four<sup>✎</sup> available types are:

-<sup>✎</sup>The last 2 are excluded since our primary concern are descendants not siblings.

> The **descendant selector** —  (**space**) — allows you to select an element nested somewhere inside another element (***not necessarily a direct descendant; it could be a grandchild***<sup>✎</sup>, for example)

<sup>✎</sup> This implies the term "direct descendant" is an alias for an "immediate child" since grandchild is obviously a descendant one step further than a child.

> The **child selector** —  **>** — allows you to select an element that is an ***immediate child*** of another element.

**…**

[**--MDN - Simple Selectors - Combinators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors#Combinators)

```html
<html>
<body>

<style>
#my_div_1 > a{
    color: red;
}


</style>
<div id="my_div_1">             
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>      
    <b> Not change my colour</b><br>            

    <div id="my_div_2">
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
    </div>  

    <a href="#">change the colour </a>  <br>        
    <b> Not change my colour</b> <br>               

    <div id="my_div_3"> 
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>        
    </div>

    <a href="#">change the colour </a> <br>
    <b> Not change my colour</b>  <br>       
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a "child combinator". All descendants in HTML are direct. The use of "selector" to describe what are now combinators was dropped from the spec years ago.

Comment: @Quentin I just edited as I was posting a link, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Quentin also replaced "direct descendants" with "immediate children". You're right "direct descendants" can be easily misconstrued for all nested `<a>`.

Comment: All descendants are "direct". All children are "immediate". The (clearly defined) technical terms are simply "descendant" and "child".

Comment: Sorry, I refer to MDN which uses the terms I've been using ...do you have something more current than May 2017 that clearly defines these terms as strictly one word each ("descendant" and "child") and discourages the use of 2 words ("direct descendant" and "immediate child" are bad grammar wise)? Please see update and inform me as how I have misunderstood this concept? All of your comments seem to enforce what's already been said...I think?

Answer (score 0):

If you will not use **>** then the CSS code will be applied to every  tag which will come after #my_div_1 so you need to use **>** to tell that you want to apply style to anchor tag which comes under div having id of **#my_div_1**

Check the below code.

```
#my_div_1 > a
{
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this.

```html
<html>
<body>

<style>
#my_div_1 > a{
    color: red;
}


</style>
<div id="my_div_1">             
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>      
    <b> Not change my colour</b><br>            

    <div id="my_div_2">
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
    </div>  

    <a href="#">change the colour </a>  <br>        
    <b> Not change my colour</b> <br>               

    <div id="my_div_3"> 
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>        
    </div>

    <a href="#">change the colour </a> <br>
    <b> Not change my colour</b>  <br>       
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `#my_div_1 > a`

```css
#my_div_1 > a{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div_1">             
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>
    <a href="#">change the colour </a><br>      
    <b> Not change my colour</b><br>            

    <div id="my_div_2">
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
    </div>  

    <a href="#">change the colour </a>  <br>        
    <b> Not change my colour</b> <br>               

    <div id="my_div_3"> 
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>
        <a href="#">Not change my colour </a><br>        
    </div>

    <a href="#">change the colour </a> <br>
    <b> Not change my colour</b>  <br>       
</div>
```